# Convert values from list of dictionaries from string to integer

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of 54 dictionaries, formatted as so:

```
[{'1A': '1',
'3E': '2',
'PRODUCT NUMBER': '1',
'Week': '1'}
,

{'1A': '1',
 '1B': '1',
 '1C': '1',
 '1D': '2',
 '1E': '2',
 '2C': '1',
 '3E': '2',
 'PRODUCT NUMBER': '2',
 'Week': '1'},...] and etc
```

I am trying to convert the values from strings to integers.

I have successfully managed to do this for my very last dictionary, but it doesnt seem to be working for the rest.

This is my code:

```
for i in buyers: #buyers is the list
    for n in buyers_dict: # the code works without this line the same, i cant figure out where to implement the 'n'
        for k, v in buyers_list.items():
            buyers_list[k] = int(v)
pprint.pprint(buyers)
```

Like I said, the 54th dictionary values are converted, but the rest are still strings

here is my excel file:

[image: Week 1 of the excel]

I've then condensed the dictionaries to just contain the key values pairs that have a value. Now I need to convert the values into integers.

Comment: You never use `n` anywhere.

Comment: The code mentions a list, but in the example data there is no list. Please create a [mre].

Comment: @Luca Can you add the data as `code`? How these rows are kept in your variable? Just a simple example would be enough.

Comment: Instead of writing *"... and etc"*, you can turn that representation into a valid Python syntax and give it a name.

Comment: the list is around the dictionaries. I will edit the code to represent this, but I've written '... and etc' because there are 54 dictionaries, all with the same format, and so I feel it would be redundant to repeatedly write them all out

Comment: @Luca yes, you are right. It would be redundant. Current version looks good. You can also delete "... and etc" part. With that said, the answers below should work for your case I think.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your data is in this schema:

```
buyers = [{...}, {...}, ...]
```

You need to loop through the list of dicts then work on those dicts in particular:

```
for d in buyers:
    for k, v in d.items():
        d[k] = int(v)
```

Or in comprehension form:

```
buyers = [{k: int(v) for k, v in d.items()} for d in buyers]
```

Comment: It wasn't me, but I bet it was because it does not result in what OP wants

Comment: I've tried this before but it didnt work for me! And for the comprehension, I get an error with "d.items()"

Comment: @Ajay I think it's because the answer was given even though question didn't have minimal reproducible example. Answering low quality posts may not be welcomed by some people.

Comment: And as you can see, @Luca says it didn't work. There is no reason for these codes to not work. But we can't know why it didn't work because we don't know what the actual data looks like.

Comment: Okay so I will add the data to the question, thank you for helping, the data is imported from a csv file, to a list of dictionaries, where every row of the csv is a dictionary. The column headers are the keys, and the cell data are the values.
However, I must say i did provide briefly what the actual data looks like.

Answer (score -2):

```
d=[{'1A': '1',
'3E': '2',
'PRODUCT NUMBER': '1',
'Week': '1'}]
```

Using  Comprehension

```
[{k:int(v)} for i in d for (k,v) in i.items() ]
```

Output:

```
[{'1A': 1}, {'3E': 2}, {'PRODUCT NUMBER': 1}, {'Week': 1}]
```